# How do code analysis, AST generation and SARIF report work in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, abstract-syntax-tree, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft-code-analysis

Recently, I became curios about mechanism of code analysis in MSBuild. I searched a lot, specially in MSDN but could not get a firm grasp on how exactly this process is done.

I want to know what components or classes, in what order, are responsible for issue tracking.
I have found some information like in C#, Roslyn is used for AST generation but I really cant understand the thorough working process.

If you don't have time to fully explain, there are two concepts I would love to understand (assume C# language):

- In other source code analysis software, AST is created and rules are compared with those AST nodes; so its a String == String strategy. I want to know if this scenario is also dominant in MSBuild or not.
- How AST is generated in MSBuild?

what I've dine so far:

searching MSDN for AST generation process,
searching MSDN for components/Classes,
googling,
searching stackoverflow